# How to use JavaScript to control audio element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Firstly I'm trying not to use the default html5 standard controls and I'd be happy to use jQuery if possible but I've taken it out for now as I was unsure of what the problem is.

At the moment I'm simply trying to have a play button which plays some music once clicked, which will change to a pause button. This pause button will then obviously pause the music once clicked.

I will leave some annotation in so you can see some of the things I have tried. Currently the play button appears but nothing happens when it is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/audio-controls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
</head>

<div id="content-container">
     <audio id="music">
     <source src="media/mexico-music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     </audio>
     <button id="play-music-button" class="play"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#play-music-button {
    height:60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-position: center;
}

.play {
    background: url("../assets/play.png") no-repeat;
}

.pause {
    background: url("../assets/pause.png") no-repeat;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var music = document.getElementById("music");
var play_music_button = document.getElementById("play-music-button");

function playAudio() {
    if (music.paused) {
        music.play();
        play_music_button.innerHTML = "Pause";
        /*play-music-button.className = "";
        play-music-button.className = "pause";*/
    } else {
        music.pause();
        play_music_button.innerHTML = "Resume";
        /*play-music-button.className = "";
        play-music-button.className = "play";*/
    }
    music.addEventListener('ended',function() {
        play_music_button.innerHTML = "Play";
    });
}
play-music-button.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
});
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code has syntax errors in it right now (`play-music-button` is not a valid identifier). It's not clear what you expect to happen by including the `addEventListener` twice.

Comment: Wasn't sure whether to add it inside the doc ready function or outside so that's the only reason it's currently in both. @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `play_music_button` as `play-music-button`, and you've defined that twice when you only need it inside of your defined function. And you need to add an `ended` event listener to set the button back to "Play"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var music = document.getElementById("music");
  var play_music_button = document.getElementById("play-music-button");

  function playAudio() {
    if (music.paused) {
      music.play();
      play_music_button.className = 'pause';
    } else {
      music.pause();
      play_music_button.className = 'play';
    }
    music.addEventListener('ended',function() {
      play_music_button.className = 'play';
    });
  }
  play_music_button.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
});
```

```css
#play-music-button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: center;
}

.play {
  background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/0/375.png") no-repeat;
}

.pause {
  background: url("http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/pause-icon-14021.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-container">
  <audio id="music">
    <source src="http://skwaat.com/clips/iloveyou.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <button id="play-music-button" class="play"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, a lot of errors have been rmoved but it's still not working. Do you think it might be because i don't have text in the button and i'm trying to use an image instead? Can't see how that would effect it but that's the onyl thing different. I will update the question with the current code @MichaelCoker

Comment: @EthanBristow what's not working? Does my demo not work? Updated my answer to change classes that trigger background image changes instead of innerHTML.

Comment: I don't suppose you could also quickly display where jQuery could be incorperated. I'd like the code to be efficient as possible and i'm trying to learn jQuery. I added it to a few variables etc but it didn't work successfully. @MichaelCoker